# PHP - How to force execution of child method

Tags: php, wordpress, class, plugins

I'm working with wordpress and i have extend a plugin class.

```
class A {
     public function languages_menu(){ ... print "en"; }
}

class B extends A {
     public function languages_menu(){ ... print "en-EN"; }
}
```

My plugin execute the parent methode and the child method :

***Result*** :

```
en
en-EN
```

I try to execute only the Child method. Knowing that i can't change the parent method

I didn't find solution yet. Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your `languages_menu()` method in Class B probably contains `parent::languages_menu()`, comment that row to see if it produces the result you are looking for.

Comment: I didn't have this line in my Class B

Comment: Can you please provide the full code of `languages_menu()` in class B and the line where you call `B->languages_menu()`?